# Что лучше: всегда присваивать переменной false, даже если она уже false, или проверять, не является ли она false, перед присваиванием?

Tags: c#, c++

Коротко. Без вникания в смысл программы, а чисто с точки зрения эффективности. Что лучше:

**вариант 1:**

```
IsOkay = true;
func();
if (IsOkay) IsOkay = false;
func2();
if (IsOkay) IsOkay = false;
func3();
if (IsOkay) IsOkay = false;
```

**вариант 2:**

```
IsOkay = true;
func();
IsOkay = false;
func2();
IsOkay = false;
func3();
IsOkay = false;
```

?

Язык C++, C# и пр, не думаю, что в данном моменте разница между си-подобными языками сильна. Я глуп, но мне интересно. Буду благодарен за объяснение!

Comment: Ну и какой смысл в проверке? что не будет лишней загрузки в память? как по мне - экономия на спичках...

Comment: Самое лучшее, это `IsOkay = func();`, не городить уйму методов и другой ерунды.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точки зрения эффективности вопрос бессмыслен: у кода на ЯВУ нет никакой локальной "эффективности". О какой-то "эффективности" такого уровня можно говорить только в отношении машинного кода. Если предварительная проверка значения переменной на `false` перед присваиванием ей `false` действительно имеет смысл с точки зрения эффективности, то компилятор с радостью будет делать это за вас.

С машинной точки зрения это действительно интересная ситуация, которая уже не раз рассматривалась ранее. Но многих современных платформах код, который избегает ненужной записи в память путем предварительного выполнения внешне "бессмысленных" чтения и проверки, во многих контекстах обладает существенно лучшим кэш-поведением и, как следствие, более высокой эффективностью. С другой стороны, из-за наличия ветвлений такой код может существенно страдать от неудачной работы процессорных алгоритмов предсказания переходов. Поэтому ничего нельзя сказать определенно без рассмотрения конкретного кода на конкретной платформе.

Но даже тогда, когда такие приемы срабатывают в качестве микро-оптимизаций, они имеют смысл лишь в определенном наборе специализированных контекстов. А вот в "обычном" коде это лишь захламляет код ненужными действиями.